# Do such numbers form a sequence? Does it have a special name?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, square-numbers

I recently had a thought about numbers having the following properties:

- A number is two less than the perfect square.
- The sum of a number's digits is equal exactly to the square root of that square.

The example of such number is $23$, because $23=25-2=5^2-2=(2+3)^2-2$.

Is there a known sequence of such numbers? If yes, does it have a special name?

Comment: $2$, $23$, and $62$ are solutions. (Well, $2$ doesn't *quite* fit, since the "nearest complete square" is actually $1$. But adjusting the definition so that the number is merely two less than "*a* complete square" helps.) A search of [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C23%2C62&language=english&go=Search) gives two hits, of which [A290226](https://oeis.org/A290226) seems the more relevant, although it isn't a match.

Comment: The sequence in question is too arbitrary to be of much interest or to have a name. Also, it is finite: 2, 23, 62, 119, 194, 287, 398.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Would you present a proof of its finiteness?

Comment: @Blue I've made an edit to clarify that I mean two less than a perfect square.

Comment: @Rusurano I encourage you to try to prove it for yourself.  Try to show that, for a sufficiently large square $n^2$, the number $x = n^2 - 2$ has a digit sum that is less than $n$.  To do this, observe that the digit sum of $x$ is bounded above by a number that is $9$ times the number of digits in $x$.

Comment: @heropup also because the exponent function grows faster than the product function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Ivan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/269518/ivan-neretin) pointed out in the comments, this supposed "sequence" is finite (having only seven terms), and seems awfully contrived to have any real meaning.

[Heropup](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/118193/heropup) also gave an outline of the proof to show the sequence has no other terms.

Perhaps there is some sort of background of the question that you need to inform us about.